# Is as.list() not possible on POSIXlt atomic vectors?

Tags: r, posixlt

`as.list()` does not work on a POSIXlt-classed atomic vector.

```
x <- as.POSIXlt(Sys.time() - 0:2)
as.list(x)
# [1] "2018-05-19 12:06:38 PDT" "2018-05-19 12:06:37 PDT" 
# [3] "2018-05-19 12:06:36 PDT"
```

So how do I easily turn the vector `x` into a list?  The only way I have found so far is to use `split()`.

```
unname(split(x, x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "2018-05-19 12:06:36 PDT"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "2018-05-19 12:06:37 PDT"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "2018-05-19 12:06:38 PDT"
```

It seems odd that `as.list()` does not work on this vector.  Is it intentional that `as.list()` does not work on POSIXlt-classed atomic vectors? And if so, why?

Comment: What is it you really want to do?  Also, try `unlist` on a `POSIXlt` or here maybe `sapply(x, unlist)`.  Does that help?  Or did you maybe want `as.list(as.POSIXct(x))` ?

Comment: Thanks @Dirk.  I had a feeling it was because of the underlying list structure of POSIXlt. I guess I'm looking for an explanation as to *why* it was decided that there wouldn't be an `as.list` method for POSIXlt. I like to know *why* :)

Comment: The `POSIXlt` type is messy. It is already a list or structure or $deity knows. Whenever possible, I operate on `POSIXct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `as.list.POSIXlt` method, so `as.list.default` is used, which does the following:

```
if (typeof(x) == "list") x else .Internal(as.vector(x, "list"))
```

Because `typeof` of your `x` is `list`, the above expression returns the `x` itself, unchanged.

It appears that `POSIXlt` objects are not atomic and not vectors -- they are lists.

```
unclass(x)  
is(unclass(x))    # list
as.data.frame(unclass(x))  # to illustrate the POSIXlt way of storing dates
```

So because a `POSIXlt` object is already a list converting it to a list results in no change.

That is different for `POSIXct`.

```
> x2 <- as.POSIXct(Sys.time() - 0:2)
> as.list(x2)
[[1]]
[1] "2018-05-19 22:25:57 EEST"

[[2]]
[1] "2018-05-19 22:25:56 EEST"

[[3]]
[1] "2018-05-19 22:25:55 EEST"
```

So if you need such conversion, you can use POSIXct instead.